# How to reshape data array from wide to long in J?

Tags: j

I like to replicate the `reshape` function in [J](https://www.jsoftware.com/).

For example, [Stata](https://www.stata.com/) can `reshape` a dataset "from wide to long". Below is their Example 1 from their [documentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dreshape.pdf):

```
. use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r11/reshape1.dta

. list
  +-------------------------------------------------------+
  | id   sex   inc80   inc81   inc82   ue80   ue81   ue82 |
  |-------------------------------------------------------|
  |  1     0    5000    5500    6000      0      1      0 |
  |  2     1    2000    2200    3300      1      0      0 |
  |  3     0    3000    2000    1000      0      0      1 |
  +-------------------------------------------------------+

. reshape long inc ue, i(id) j(year)

. list
  +-----------------------------+
  | id   year   sex    inc   ue |
  |-----------------------------|
  |  1     80     0   5000    0 |
  |  1     81     0   5500    1 |
  |  1     82     0   6000    0 |
  |  2     80     1   2000    1 |
  |  2     81     1   2200    0 |
  |  2     82     1   3300    0 |
  |  3     80     0   3000    0 |
  |  3     81     0   2000    0 |
  |  3     82     0   1000    1 |
  +-----------------------------+
```

NB. Python Pandas has a similar function ("[stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)").

I understand that J can import the data files (csv format) as follows.

```
load 'web/gethttp'
] dataset =: gethttp 'https://bbbyc.github.io/reshape1.csv'

load 'tables/csv'
] dataInJArray =: fixcsv dataset
```

I am lost after getting this `dataInJArray`. How can I reshape it? Appreciate any hints / advice!

Comment: I think you probably want to look at jd which is in the addons/data/jd after you have uploaded it through the Package Manager. Have you looked at that or is this an exercise that you wish to do independently as a learning opportunity?

Comment: Thanks, Bob. Can you point me to the jd function? I looked at the [jd tutorials](https://www.jsoftware.com/jd_tuts.html), and I see some SQL-like functions (e.g., filter, ordering, insert, delete, admin tools, reading from CSV), but I don't see a function for reshaping. 

Initially, I was hoping to use the J base library ([transpose](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/barco), together with some "groupby") to replicate the above Stata's reshape example, but I can't find something that would work.

Comment: If you have seen the tutorials then I think that you have seen a lot of the documentation. There is this link https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Jd/Overview and you can always open the actual scripts /addons/data/jd/jd.ijs to see the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually work on your specific problem using J you could do this:

```
NB. t is the data to be stacked:

   [ t=: 3 8 $ 1 0 5000 5500 6000 0 1 0   2 1 2000 2200 3300 1 0 0   3 0 3000 2000 1000 0 0 1 
1 0 5000 5500 6000 0 1 0
2 1 2000 2200 3300 1 0 0
3 0 3000 2000 1000 0 0 1
```

you can select and combine the different columns appropriately

```
   ({. ,. 1&{ ,. (2 3 4 & {),. (5 6 7 & {))"1 t
1 0 5000 0
1 0 5500 1
1 0 6000 0

2 1 2000 1
2 1 2200 0
2 1 3300 0

3 0 3000 0
3 0 2000 0
3 0 1000 1
```

Since this leaves gaps between the groups, you apply `,/` to the whole result

```
   ,/@:(({. ,. 1&{ ,. (2 3 4 & {),. (5 6 7 & {))"1) t
1 0 5000 0
1 0 5500 1
1 0 6000 0
2 1 2000 1
2 1 2200 0
2 1 3300 0
3 0 3000 0
3 0 2000 0
3 0 1000 1
```

I am not sure how well this generalizes, but variations could be used on tables of any number of records if they are already organized appropriately.

To finish off the formatting and the introduction of 'years'

```
   [s1=. ,. each <"1  |: s0  NB. years inserted in the next step
+-+-+----+-+
|1|0|5000|0|
|1|0|5500|1|
|1|0|6000|0|
|2|1|2000|1|
|2|1|2200|0|
|2|1|3300|0|
|3|0|3000|0|
|3|0|2000|0|
|3|0|1000|1|
+-+-+----+-+
   [s2=. ({. , ,.@:(9 $ 80 81 82"_); }.)s1  NB. 80 81 82"_ creates a verb that returns 80 81 82 given any argument
+-+--+-+----+-+
|1|80|0|5000|0|
|1|81|0|5500|1|
|1|82|0|6000|0|
|2|80|1|2000|1|
|2|81|1|2200|0|
|2|82|1|3300|0|
|3|80|0|3000|0|
|3|81|0|2000|0|
|3|82|0|1000|1|
+-+--+-+----+-+
   ('id';'year';'sex';'inc';'ue'),:s2
+--+----+---+----+--+
|id|year|sex|inc |ue|
+--+----+---+----+--+
|1 |80  |0  |5000|0 |
|1 |81  |0  |5500|1 |
|1 |82  |0  |6000|0 |
|2 |80  |1  |2000|1 |
|2 |81  |1  |2200|0 |
|2 |82  |1  |3300|0 |
|3 |80  |0  |3000|0 |
|3 |81  |0  |2000|0 |
|3 |82  |0  |1000|1 |
+--+----+---+----+--+
```